# How can I fit or obtain an equation from this surface? [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, model, curve-fitting

I have the following surface (X, Y, Z). Here Z is the dependent variable, and X and Y are the entry parameters. This data comes from tests (I measured variable Z from specific X and Y values). I need to generate an equation to predict Z such as Z = f(X, Y).

[Surface data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCxLU.png)

- I know that Z grows exponentially with X, so my model is something like exp1 = a*e^(b*X).
- I also know that Z grows linearly in the Y-direction, so the model is poly1 = a*X + b.

I tried following an article on Mathworks but I got no where.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: Only with an image and without data nothing serious can be done.

Comment: would it be possible for you to make available to readers the code used to generate the surface above mentioned? it would greatly assist, thanks

Comment: Simulated data can be generated using something like `[x, y] = meshgrid(1:10, 1:10); z = 3*y.*(exp(x/4)+2)+20+40*rand(10, 10); figure; surface(x,y,z);view(3);`. I think the question is more along the lines of, how do you fit something like `z=A*(y+B)*(exp(C*x)+D)+E`, which is a reasonable question, but may gain more traction on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Prelims: generate mock data

```
[x, y] = meshgrid(1:10, 1:10);
z = 3*(y+2).*(exp(x/4)+2)+40+20*rand(10, 10);
```

If desired, this can be visualised using `figure; surface(x,y,z);view(3);`.

---

To make a custom fit, we can use the inbuilt [`fit`](https://au.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html?s_tid=doc_ta#d124e32743) and [`fittype`](https://au.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fittype.html#btpaend-8) functions.

```
% Note that we can create any custom function here, 
% as long as the parameter names are updated 
myFittype = fittype('a*(y+b)*(exp(c*x)+d)+e', ...
        'dependent', 'z', 'independent', {'x', 'y'}, ...
        'coefficients', {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'});
myFit = fit([x(:), y(:)], z(:), myFittype);
```

This does quite a good job at estimating the parameters:

```
     General model:
     myFit(x,y) = a*(y+b)*(exp(c*x)+d)+e
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):     [Actual values]
       a =       3.084  (2.665, 3.504)              3
       b =       2.285  (1.972, 2.597)              2
       c =      0.2452  (0.2334, 0.2571)            0.25
       d =       1.901  (1.359, 2.444)              2
       e =       46.84  (39.59, 54.1)               40
```

and the whole thing can be visualised using `plot`:

```
figure; plot(myFit, [x(:), y(:)], z(:));
```

Comment: This seems like what I need. I'll give it a try. Thank you!